# Code first Setting up One to Many Relation between Two table

Tags: ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have the following Classes which represent exact table fields. What is the proper way to set up the Relationship so that i can Query related field using Entity Frame Work.

I want to use Data Annotation and want to be explicit in specifying relation rather than using convention based.
Each Group can have Many Skills.

var SkillsGrouped = da.sv_SkillGroups.Include("Sv_Skills");
 I am getting error which mentions that could not map field Name, in fact the field that it complains about is not the part of either Table.

```
[Table("sv_Skill")]
    public class sv_Skill
    {
        [Required]
    [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(4000)]
        public string skillDescription { get; set; }
        public int? skillGroupId { get; set; } //References id column in sv_SkillGroup table
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? createdOn { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string updatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? updatedOn { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string status { get; set; }
    }


[Table("sv_SkillGroup")]
    public class sv_SkillGroup
    {

        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(4000)]
        public string skillGroupDescription { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? createdOn { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string updatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? updatedOn { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string status { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<sv_Skill> sv_Skills { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Where is `sv_SevaSkill` class declaration?

Comment: it is actuall sv_skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you not properly set one endpoint of many-to-one relation at class
sv_Skill declaration, correct it like this:

```
[Table("sv_Skill")]
public class sv_Skill
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4000)]
    public string skillDescription { get; set; }

    public int? skillGroupId { get; set; }
    //this new field was added - link to sv_SkillGroup as foreign key via
    //field skillGroupId above
    public sv_SkillGroup skillGroup { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? createdOn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string updatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updatedOn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Drop your current migration with this tables and recreate it with new code.

Comment: After recreating the Tables involved in the relation ship it worked